# How to convert string array to JSON array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have string array like this:

```
"[totRev=248634.29858677526, totEBITDA=34904.9893085068, EBITDA_Operating_Cash_Flow_Margin=0.140386863387, debt_Service_Coverage_Ratio=16.7793849967, gross_Debt_to_EBITDA=0.3626422278, gross_Debt=50632.09233331651, cash_Available_for_Debt=102746.09168349924, debt_Servicing_Amount=6123.352655871018]"
```

How do I convert this either into a JSON Array or a JSON object like

```
{totRev:'248634.29858677526',....etc}
```

Comment: one word .. do it carefully ... note, your expected "Object" is not valid JS ... seems like you want the object to be like `{totRev: 248634.29858677526, totEBITDA: 34904.9893085068, ...}` or, as JSON, `{"totRev": 248634.29858677526, "totEBITDA": 34904.9893085068, ...}` - oh, and there's no such thing as a `JSON array` - unless you are referring to an array of JSON strings, which is not relevant to this at all

Comment: `str.split(', ').reduce((p,c) => { const parts = c.split('='); p[parts[0] = [arts[1]; return p;]}, {})`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake actually want in json object like {totRev:248634.29858677526,....}

Comment: no such thing as a **JSON object** either - JSON is a STRING representation of a javascript object, but it isn't an object

Comment: Three steps: 1. remove the braces, 2. split by `, `, and 3. split the resulting items by `=`.

Comment: HI Rajesh i have tried you suggestion on console of chrome it throws an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; at location [arts[1]; return p;]}

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH There is a typo. Please read the code before using it. :-p `= [arts[1]` should be `= parts[1]`

Comment: @Rajesh do'nt you think  at p[parts[0] should have closing ']' for reference  p[parts[0] = [arts[1]; return p;]}, {})

Answer (score 9):

Use `substring`, `split` and `reduce`

```
str.substring( 1,str.length - 1 ) //remove [ and ] from the string
    .split(",") //split by ,
    .reduce( (a,b) => (i = b.split("="), a[i[0]] = i[1], a ) , {} );
```

**Reduce explanation**

- **Split** `b` (element in the array such as `totRev=248634.29858677526`) by `=`
- **Assign** the first item in the array as key to `a` (accumulator initialized as `{}`) and value as second item of the array
- **Return** `a`

**Demo**

```js
var str = "[totRev=248634.29858677526, totEBITDA=34904.9893085068, EBITDA_Operating_Cash_Flow_Margin=0.140386863387, debt_Service_Coverage_Ratio=16.7793849967, gross_Debt_to_EBITDA=0.3626422278, gross_Debt=50632.09233331651, cash_Available_for_Debt=102746.09168349924, debt_Servicing_Amount=6123.352655871018]";
var output = str.substring(1,str.length-1).split(",").reduce( (a,b) => (i = b.split("="), a[i[0].trim()] = i[1], a ) , {} );
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @guruvinder372, can you explain this part `.reduce( (a,b) => (i = b.split("="), a[i[0]] = i[1], a ) , {} )` ?

Comment: @guruvinder372 its a great and optimised solution.